# F#: can I extend a module with additional module by just referencing another assembly?

Tags: .net-core, f#

I'm working on a tiny F# ADO.NET "wrapper" (yes, yet another one, besides [Zaid Ajaj's Npgsql.FSharp](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Npgsql.FSharp), [Pim Brouwers's Donald](https://github.com/pimbrouwers/Donald) and many others on GitHub), and I am thinking about extending the support for different ADO.NET providers...

Basically I have a core project (ie. `Michelle.Sql.Core`) that contains the core types + functions, a bit similar to Dapper:

```ml
type IDbValue<'DbConnection, 'DbParameter
    when 'DbConnection :> DbConnection
    and 'DbParameter :> DbParameter> =

    abstract ToParameter: string -> 'DbParameter

type CommandDefinition<'DbConnection, 'DbParameter, 'DbType
    when 'DbConnection :> DbConnection
    and 'DbParameter :> DbParameter
    and 'DbType :> IDbValue<'DbConnection, 'DbParameter>> =
    { Statement: Statement
      Parameters: (string * 'DbType) list
      CancellationToken: CancellationToken
      Timeout: TimeSpan
      StoredProcedure: bool
      Prepare: bool
      Transaction: DbTransaction option }
```

First thing, you might think "Wosh there is a lot generics ornamenting your type definitions!".

Alright so first things first I'm trying to work around some limitations, most notable this one: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/255 (along with its good [friend](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/162)), thought I could circumvent that issue by creating a C# project and forcing constraints in that project, it doesn't work out.

The reason I need that many generic constraints is that I want a strongly-typed connection that kinda "flow" through the calls setting the values of the different fields of that record, for example:

```ml
let playWithSQLite() = 
    use connection = new SQLiteConnection()
    Sql.statement "INSERT INTO aTable (aColumn) VALUES(@aNumber);"
    |> Sql.prepare true
    |> Sql.timeout (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.))
    |> Sql.parameters [("aNumber", SqliteDbValue.Integer 42L)]
    |> Sql.executeNonQuery connection
```

Fyi, `SqliteDbValue` is defined in different assembly `Michelle.Sql.Sqlite`:

```
// https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
type SqliteDbValue =
    | Null
    | Integer of int64
    | Real of double
    | Text of string
    | Blob of byte array
    interface IDbValue<SQLiteConnection, SQLiteParameter> with
        member this.ToParameter(name) =
            let parameter = SQLiteParameter()
            // Not so secret impl. goes here...
            parameter
```

The code above works, basically, the `CommandDefinition` record is populated via different calls defined in the core library through a `Sql` module (decorated with `RequiredAccessAttribute`).

The problem arise when the use needs to explicitly indicates the generic return type...

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Sql = 

    // [...]

    let executeNonQuery
        (connection: 'DbConnection when 'DbConnection :> DbConnection)
        (commandDefinition: CommandDefinition<'DbConnection, 'DbParameter, 'DbType>
            when 'DbConnection :> DbConnection
            and 'DbParameter :> DbParameter
            and 'DbType :> IDbValue<'DbConnection, 'DbParameter>) =
        async { 
            // Not so secret impl. goes here
        }

    let executeScalar<'Scalar, .. >
        (connection: 'DbConnection when 'DbConnection :> DbConnection)
        (commandDefinition: CommandDefinition<'DbConnection, 'DbParameter, 'DbType>
            when 'DbConnection :> DbConnection
            and 'DbParameter :> DbParameter
            and 'DbType :> IDbValue<'DbConnection, 'DbParameter>) =
        async { 
            // Not so secret impl. goes here
        }
```

So you see, in the case of the `executeScalar` function above, since one type has to be made explicit, it means every other generic parameter has now to be made explicit when calling that function, [otherwise they are defaulted to `obj`](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/885), which among other things means that the end-user now needs to input 4 generic parameters:

```
// [...] setting up the CommandDefinition...
|> Sql.executeScalar<int64, SQLiteConnection, SQLiteParameter, SqliteDbValue> connection
```

and this is exactly the kind of things I would like to avoid while retaining the connection consistency.

What I tried and which is rather a clunky solution is to implement a reduced version of the `executeScalar`, and what I mean by:

```ml
module Michelle.Sql.Sqlite


[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Sql =
    let executeScalar<'Scalar> connection commandDefinition =
        Sql.executeScalar<'Scalar, SQLiteConnection, SQLiteParameter, SqliteDbValue>
            connection
            commandDefinition
```

But the thing with strategy is that it essentially boils down to shadowing:

Hence this code below doesn't work:

```ml
open Michelle.Sql.Sqlite
open Michelle.Sql.Core

// [...] setting up the CommandDefinition... connection being an instance of SQLiteConnection
|> Sql.executeScalar<int64> connection
```

While that one does:

```ml
open Michelle.Sql.Core
open Michelle.Sql.Sqlite

// [...] setting up the CommandDefinition... connection being an instance of SQLiteConnection
|> Sql.executeScalar<int64> connection
```

I wish there could be a solution, I even though about static classes, but partial classes can't be defined across several assemblies.

I know that overloading is not possible with F# module functions and shadowing doesn't look like a viable solution in terms of developer experience.

So, is there any solution out there? (Putting aside creating another function with a different name or a different module with also a different name)

Comment: Not really an answer but why don't you rename your original module to CoreSQL then you can create modules for each driver type e.g. Sql.execluteScalar<'T> = CoreSql.executeScalar<'T,SQLLiteConnection, etc.  and provide aliasing to every single function and never expose CoreSQL.

Comment: @KoenigLear This is pretty much what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Koenig Lear suggested:

> Not really an answer but why don't you rename your original module to CoreSQL then you can create modules for each driver type e.g. `Sql.execluteScalar<'T>` = `CoreSql.executeScalar<'T,SQLLiteConnection, etc`. and provide aliasing to every single function and never expose CoreSQL.

and this is pretty much what I ended up doing:

```ml
// open stuff goes here...

type SqliteCommandDefinition = CommandDefinition<SQLiteConnection, SQLiteParameter, SqliteDbValue>

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Sqlite =

    // Other functions irrelevant to this post

    let executeScalar<'Scalar> connection (commandDefinition: SqliteCommandDefinition) =
        Sql.executeScalar<'Scalar, _, _, _>
            connection
            commandDefinition

    let executeNonQuery connection (commandDefinition: SqliteCommandDefinition) =
        Sql.executeNonQuery connection commandDefinition
```